# how to use <,> tags in java when create xml file

Tags: java, xml

I want to html tag in xml. I'm using CDATA it is run in xml but I create xml file with java <, > tags was "<". I don't understand this situation.

```
String returnUrl="<![CDATA[ac=S<br/>DNbZCQOijAl6HrAAyyGV]]>";
Node returnUrlNode = doc.createElement("returnurl");
returnUrlNode.setTextContent(returnUrl);
userNode.appendChild(returnUrlNode);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for whatever reason you want the text to be in a CDATA section and not a simple text node, you'll need to create the CDATA yourself. I'm assuming you're using the DOM and not some API that looks similar, so it would be:

```
Node returnUrlNode = doc.createElement("returnurl");
returnUrlNode.appendChild(
    doc.createCDATASection(
        "Whatever text you wanted to go in here, including unescaped < and >."));
```

Note that like SLaks pointed out, when the DOM is serialized, all escaping will happen automatically. (In this case, that means that the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` will be added automatically.) This is just how you'd create an actual CDATA section if you need the output to be a CDATA section and not a normal text node.

Answer (score 3):

The Java XML APIs will automatically escape your content.

You can just write `.setTextContent("ac=S<br/>DNbZCQOijAl6HrAAyyGV")`, and Java will excape the `<` and `>` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the XML escape characters:

> ```
> & &amp; 
> < &lt; 
> > &gt; 
> " &quot; 
> ' &apos;
> ```